# No package blktrace available

Tags: yum

I could not install blktrace in my redhat5.8 OS.

```
 yum install blktrace
Loaded plugins: katello, product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
No package blktrace available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Are you subscribed to RHN?

Comment: And did you subscribe with Subscription Manager or RHN Classic? You probably need to call Red Hat to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your system...

```
[root@Citrus ~]# yum search blktrace
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * rpmforge: ftp.lug.ro
==================== Matched: blktrace 
blktrace.x86_64 : Utilities for performing block layer IO tracing in the linux kernel
```

If you're in a pinch and don't have an active RHN subscription, just download the CentOS binary. There aren't any dependencies for `blktrace`, so you can obtain a compatible version from: [**mirrors.centos.org - blktrace**](http://mirror.centos.org/centos-5/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/blktrace-1.0.0-6.el5.x86_64.rpm).

---

Edit:

Kill all `yum` processes on the system. `rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*`. Then rebuild the RPM database with `rpm --rebuilddb`. Maybe even a `yum clean all` for good measure.

Then try again.

---

Edit:

Please follow the steps to fix your yum at:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unable-to-read-consumer-identity-rhn-yum-warning/

Comment: I can give him RHEL5.8 rpm

Comment: [root@rw gfs]# rpm -ivh blktrace-1.0.0-6.el5.x86_64.rpm
warning: blktrace-1.0.0-6.el5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 192a7d7d
warning: waiting for transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000

Comment: Getting the above warnings while trying to install with the rpm

Comment: @Angus See edit above.

Comment: How to kill all yum process? I did ps -aef | grep yum. And found none. Is this the correct way

Comment: rpm --rebuild is showing this warning ..    warning: waiting for transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000

Comment: That should be `rpm --rebuilddb`

Comment: Sorry typo error even rpm --rebuilddb is showing this warning: waiting for transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000
 for long

Comment: [root@rw gfs]# yum search blktrace
Loaded plugins: katello, product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Warning: No matches found for: blktrace
No Matches found

Comment: I'm getting the above error for everything I try.. Like yum install make, yum install git-core

Comment: K. Try `lsof /var/lib/rpm/__db.000`

Comment: @ewwhite: Its not listing anything

Comment: And `yum clean all`?

Comment: [root@rw gfs]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: katello, product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Cleaning up Everything

Comment: I'm getting the above errors when done .. yum clean all

Comment: @Angus Please follow the steps at: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unable-to-read-consumer-identity-rhn-yum-warning/

Comment: @ewwhite : Thanks for explaining patiently :-) . I will do it as the step says. Thanks.

Comment: @ewwhite : Tha also didn't help. Still getting the same error while doing yum clean all and yum install packagename. Mine is RHEL5.8

Comment: @angus If you have a valid Red Hat subscription, call Red Hat.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the database is locked, either by another package install or a stale lock. Do you have any other package installs pending? If not, you can ^C out of the build, remove the lock file (as long as you are sure that there are no other current or pending package installs), and try once again.

First check what has the file tied up:
lsof /var/lib/rpm/__db.000

Next,  check to see the file size, many times it is zero size.
ls -l /var/lib/rpm/__db.000

If it is of zero size, lets touch it to recreate it and set permissions:
touch /var/lib/rpm/__db.000
chown root:root /var/lib/rpm/__db.000
chmod 644 /var/lib/rpm/__db.000

You could also try setting "gpgcheck" to "0" temporarily for the package install (remember to change it back):

vi /etc/yum.conf

Change:
gpgcheck=1

To:
gpgcheck=0